# Returning results with special characters while searching for regular characters

Tags: php, mysql, special-characters

I have a database table with names that occasionally have special characters in them, for example: Klünnen.
I'm querying the table as follows: SELECT * FROM members WHERE name LIKE '%$search_name%'.

I would like to return names with special characters even if users don't use special characters when searching. For example, when searching for 'Klunnen' instead of 'Klünnen'.

Is this possible? How would this work?